# How do you get VS Code to run "python" instead of " & C:/Users/[username]/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe"?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

In the screenshot of the [VS Code Python Tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_run-hello-world), it shows the following command being run at the terminal after selecting "Run Python File at Terminal":

```
python c:/py/hello/hello.py
```

[image]

When I run a Python file the same way, I get:

```
& C:/Users/[username]/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe c:/py/hello/hello.py
```

Is there a setting so that it will just run `python` instead of `& C:/Users/[username]/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe`?

**EDIT**
Here's my Python Path setting 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you see is the full path to the Python version you are using as per your current settings.

Check [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments)

> Selecting an interpreter sets the python.pythonPath value in your workspace settings to the path of the interpreter. To see the setting, select File > Preferences > Settings (Code > Preferences > Settings on macOS), then select the Workspace Settings tab.
>
> Note: If you select an interpreter without a workspace folder open, VS Code sets python.pythonPath in your user settings instead, which sets the default interpreter for VS Code in general. The user setting makes sure you always have a default interpreter for Python projects. The workspace settings lets you override the user setting.

To switch between different Python interpreters you have, you can do this.

From "view" in the menu bar select command palette ( or , then type in the search bar "Python: Select Interpreter", the different interpreters you have will show in results and you can pick the one you want

Comment: I've added a picture showing that my Python Path setting is just "python". Do you know if there's a way to just get it to run the `python` command instead of the full path to the executable?